# Which one is a Ruby deprecated proc?

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc, ruby-1.8

In the book *Programming Ruby: The Pragmatic Programmers Guide* by Dave Thomas with Chad Fowler and Andy Hunt, regarding the creation of `Proc`s there is a footnote that states:

> "There’s actually a third, proc, but it is effectively deprecated."

I could not find which way is this. I am aware of the following ways to create a `Proc`:

1

```
b = lambda { | msg | puts "msg: #{msg}" }
b.call("hi")
```

2

```
def create_block_object(&block)
  block
end
b = create_block_object{ |msg| puts "msg: #{msg}" }
b.call("hello")
```

3

```
b = Proc.new { |msg| puts "msg: #{msg}"}
b.call("hey")
```

I want to know the fourth way and would be glad if somebody would give me an answer.

Comment: Could you quote exactly what the book say?

Comment: @fmendez thanks for response. It's what a book says at a footnote `6. There’s actually a third, proc, but it is effectively deprecated.`

@sawa big thanks for an edit

Comment: Number 1 is deprecated since Ruby 1.9 in favor of the notation in davidrac's answer.

Comment: thank you @sawa, it's clear now

Comment: @sawa: do you have a source for `lambda` being deprecated? It's clear from Black's book that the `Kernel#proc` method is the one he means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book you are referring to is on Ruby 1.8.

In that version of Ruby, `lambda` and `procs` are effectively aliases, while `Proc` is a different beast. This is obviously misleading, which is why it is not recommended that you use `proc` as in

```
prc = proc {|x, y| puts x + y}
```

This syntax is considered deprecated and it is recommended using lambda in this case.

This is no longer valid for later versions of Ruby, starting with 1.9.

Comment: thanks, I found out that you were right since book never mentioned a method you provided

Comment: Actually, `Kernel#proc` is equivalent to `Kernel#lambda` before Ruby 1.9, and equivalent to `Proc.new` in 1.9 (not sure about 2.0). For this reason Black cautions against using it (since the semantics of lambda and non-lambda `Procs` are different). This is written in a footnote in the section "Blocks, Closures, and Proc Objects" in Chapter 22 ("The Ruby Language").

Answer (score 1):

This is another syntax for lambdas:

```
b = ->(msg) { puts "msg: #{msg}" }
b.call("hi")
```

Comment: thanks, I know that, it is also present since Ruby 1.9 and it is not really deprecated, I guess

Answer (score 0):

prc = proc {|x| x*x} has been depreciated.

This syntax was process was predominantly used in Ruby-1.8.7 versions.